# What is different in different user accounts when doing a maven build

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I've been trying to do a maven build of this project.  It downloads a lot of artifacts from a repository and builds fine on one account (local account).  However, when i log into a network account(same computer) with the same eclipse/maven installation, same workspace, same environment variables(I only have 2 user ones),  it fails because it tries to read from a different directory that doesn't exist (C:/schema/blah/blah/blah) when it should be reading from (C:/workspace/Echo/target/main/xsd/blah/blah/blah)

Is there something inside eclipse or maven that stores local users settings i could look into.  The code for this project would be nearly impossible to post since it has ~30 jar files.  I'm at a loss.

Thank you in advance to anyone who has ideas or suggestions

~Ryan

Answer (score 0):

check the `.m2/settings.xml` file in both user home directories.  You may want to set the `<localRepository>` to the same (shared) location so it does not download the same artifacts from remote repositories twice.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response krock.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response krock.  I deleted the .m2/settings.xml file which i believe forces it to use the one in apache-maven/config/settings.xml.  This has the repository here C:/maven-repo.  However, for some reason on the second test account that i created, its still downloading it to <user name>.m2/repository/artifacts.  Ideas?